# Push vertices when object pushes on another object with geometry nodes in blender 3.1

Tags: mesh, objects, geometry-nodes

I looked at similar answers but they don't satisfy my needs. because the only answers are cloth sims and displace modifiers.

Kind of like a very cheap softbody sim but it doesn't need the ripple calc.

[image]

Comment: i could offer soft body physics as another solution... ;)

Comment: @JohnMC I have tried it and what i want is very simple vertex displacement and softbody takes too long to compute as it tries to calculate unnecessary forces.

Comment: I'm not sure GN is up to par for such mesh modification currently without jumping through multiple hoops. But you can explore a combination of hook modifier + laplacian deform modifier I think. not my area of expertise so I can't offer a proper example

Comment: @Gorgious yeah there is a answer like that but the thing is I am working on a humanoid character and the Laplacian deform method works really well with relatively flat surfaces

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)